# Change items position in List<string>

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, list

I have one list with 3 items

```
reg.ToList()    Count = 3   System.Collections.Generic.List<string>
[0] "Text0" string
[1] "Text1" string
[2] "Text2" string
```

I want to change all item positions, first postion instead last one, and remaining items to stand up with one position

for this example

```
[0] "Text1" string
[1] "Text2" string
[2] "Text0" string
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you could remove and re-add the first item in the list. This way your value will be at the end of the list

```
var item = reg[0];
reg.Remove(item); //Removes the specific item
reg.Add(item); //add's an item to the end of the list
```

this will also work with bigger lists and the index will change accordingly

EDIT: Crono's solution will work faster then mine :s

Answer (score 12):

Use [`RemoveAt`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5cw9x18z%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method right after getting ahold of your first item, then add it back.

```
var item = list[0];
list.RemoveAt(0);
list.Add(item);
```

`RemoveAt` will be more efficient than `Remove` because it won't try to search through your list and compare values needlessly.

Comment: +1 nice to know RemoveAt removes at the specified index; EDIT, surely the +1 with the comparison explanation

Comment: @Schuere, it is much nicer to know that you can rely on the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) :-)

Comment: @Elgonzo, sometimes i do find SO more helpfull than some documentation :-)

Comment: @Schuere, actually, i have to wholeheartedly agree with you there :-D